# The 'config' trait of a Map instance must be a Config, but a value of class 'dict' (i.e. {'api_key': 'AI##'}) was specified

Tags: python, google-maps, jupyter

Environment Details:
Python-3.6, [gmaps](https://github.com/pbugnion/gmaps) - 0.6.1

Code :

```
gmaps.configure(api_key="AI--Mykey") # Fill in with your API key
fig = gmaps.figure()
```

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you should update your `ipywidgets`. Take a look at [this issue](https://github.com/pbugnion/gmaps/issues/178).

Comment: I'm the main author of jupyter-gmaps -- Upgrading to ipywidgets 7.x seems to resolve the issue some of the time, but not all the time. If it doesn't, monitor [issue 182](https://github.com/pbugnion/gmaps/issues/182). I'll post on that when we find a permanent fix.